# How use proxy for QEMU?

Tags: networking, proxy, qemu

I have QEMU for emulating, and I have to start it from terminal (I'm using `qemu-system-x86_64`), but on host machine to have access the network I got to use proxy `<host_ip>:<host_port>`. I want QEMU to redirect all network requests to `<host_ip>:<host_port>`, where I have a proxy, is there a way to do it from host? May be using `-netdev` or another option?

***UPD***:

Let's say I want to do `# apt update` on the guest QEMU, so I need to be connected to the network, but the only way this can be done is via host proxy.

> If I'm not mistaken, QEMU, by default, will redirect the request to `10.0.2.2` gateway, then it will forward the request somewhere (tbh, I don't know where) and tries to reach the network.

So, I have a port on my host machine, let's say `12345`. `apt` config on the host looks like:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<host_ip>:12345/";
```

I want the similar for the guest QEMU, let's say:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<guest_ip>:<guest_port>"
```

Here `<guest_port>` is some port on guest QEMU machine and `<guest_ip>` is guest's IP address. When `apt` tries  to reach smth, its request should be redirected to the `<guest_ip>:<guest_port>`, which should be redirected to the host's `12345` port, where the actual proxy is set.

This is just an example how it can be done (in theory, maybe), but as a way QEMU may redirect all network request to host specific port (`12345`) without any proxy on the guest, but I don't know how to do it :)

This is related not only for `apt`. `apt` here is only an example.

So, I want QEMU to redirect network request from guest to host on a specific port. Is there a way to do so?

> I think `hostfwd` now is not the thing I want, because it will redirect to the guest some requests, but I already have smth that listening on `12345` port.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A walkaround is using ssh tunnel.

Adding this line to your `qemu` startup script redirects the requests to port 10022 on your host to port 22 on your `qemu` emulator. (22 is the default ssh port)

```bash
-netdev user,id=net0,hostfwd=tcp::10022-:22
```

Then make a reverse proxy like this

```bash
ssh -R 1234:<proxy_ip>:<proxy_port> -p 10022 localhost
```

Now your qemu guest has access to your proxy on its port 1234.